# Single Validation in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am very new to Laravel, and our system uses multiple forms within a single page to insert the single bitcoin wallet into each input field, but as it stands the user is able to use it on all inputs and this is wrong as could i make only one valid? such as "username" "email" etc ..

html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/wallet3-edit/update">
    <div class="form-group hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
    </div>

 <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('bitzpayer_id3') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="bitzpayer_id3" class="control-label"><b>Wallet:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="bitzpayer_id3" placeholder="Please enter your Wallet here" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->bitzpayer_id3 }}"/>

        <?php if ($errors->has('bitzpayer_id3')) :?>
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{$errors->first('bitzpayer_id3')}}</strong>
        </span>
        <?php endif;?>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning text-white"> Submit </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Wallet3Controller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update user profile & make backend push to DB
     * 
    **/

    public function index() {

        /**
         * fetching the user model
         **/
        $user = Auth::user();
        //var_dump($user);

        /**
         * Passing the user data to profile view
         */
        return view('/wallet3-edit', compact('user'));

    }

public function update(Request $request) {

  /**
     * fetching the user model
     */
    $user = Auth::user();


    /**
     * Validate request/input 
     **/
    $this->validate($request, [
        'bitzpayer_id3' => 'max:255|unique:users,bitzpayer_id3,'.$user->id,
    ]);

    /**
     * storing the input fields name & email in variable $input
     * type array
     **/
    $input = $request->only('bitzpayer_id3');



    /**
     * Accessing the update method and passing in $input array of data
     **/
    $user->update($input);

    /**
     * after everything is done return them pack to /profile/ uri
     **/
    return back();
  }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('wallet3-edit', 'Wallet3Controller@index');
Route::patch('wallet3-edit/{id}', 'Wallet3Controller@update');
```

Comment: Can you explain more? Do you have multiple forms/input in one single page and you want to make their input unique? or i misunderstand you

Comment: yes, exact. There are 13 forms on the same page, I want to save all wallet addresses typed in the input but so can not duplicate. The database table are
 bitzpayer_id, bitzpayer_id2, bitzpayer_id3 ...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to validate not duplication in a single page:
because The page dosent send any request to server until the form completes,
you can check this within  javascript/jquery like this:

```
$(".inputs").change(function(){
    if($("#input1").val()==$("#input2").val()){
       $("#input1").addClass("error");
     }
});
```

but if your input are seprated in different pages and save in database you can validate with them with this kind of rules in Laravel controller or Laravel Request Class:

```
 $validationRules = ["wallet" => "required|unique:wallets_table,btc"];
```

where "wallet" is the name of your input field. "wallets_table" is your database table and "btc" is table column.

but if you are not willing to save the wallet public keys in Database and the requests are from a single user, you can save the "Address"es in a Session Array and check them out when a user submit a request. but this solution works **User Scope** .

please give me more details if I misunderstood.

Comment: Actually there are 13 forms on the same page, I want to save all wallet addresses typed in the input but so cannot duplicate. The database table are
 bitzpayer_id, bitzpayer_id2, bitzpayer_id3 ...

Comment: when all of them are in a same page you have to check them with **javascript**

Comment: like this, usinq Jquey:
    $(".inputs").change(function(){
    if($("#input1").val()==$("#input2").val()){
       $("#input1").addClass("error");
     }
});